# Display next 5 days excluding Sundays in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am displaying the following code for next 5 days

```
function setDateTime() {
    var timesOffice = (officeTimes[officeID] + "").split(",");
    //alert(officeTimes[officeID]+":12:"+timesOffice[0]);
    var dt = new Date(correctDate);
    var dateOptions = "";
    var firstdateString = "";
    var totalDays = 5;
    for (i = 0; i < totalDays; i++) {

        var sateString = dt.getFullYear() + " " + monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + " " + (dt.getDate());
        //console.log("i:"+i+"s:"+sateString);
        dateFlag = 0;
        var j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < timesOffice.length; j++) {

            if (checkValidDateTime(sateString, timesOffice[j])) {
                dateFlag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        if (dateFlag == 0) {
            totalDays++;
            continue;
        }
        if (firstdateString == "") firstdateString = sateString;
        dateOptions = dateOptions + '<option value="' + sateString + '">' + sateString + '</option>';


    }
    $(".date").html(dateOptions);
}
```

I want to exclude Sundays from this list

Answer (score 1):

You can tell what day of the week a `Date` instance represents using its [`getDay` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.16):

```
if (dt.getDay() === 0) {
    // It's Sunday
}
else {
    // It isn't
}
```

I figure you can take it from there... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getDay method to get the day of the week:

```
function setDateTime() {
    var timesOffice = (officeTimes[officeID] + "").split(",");
    //alert(officeTimes[officeID]+":12:"+timesOffice[0]);
    var dt = new Date(correctDate);
    var dateOptions = "";
    var firstdateString = "";
    var totalDays = 5;
    int i=0;
    while(i<totalDays) {

        if(dt.getDay() != 0) // exclude Sundays
        {
            var sateString = dt.getFullYear() + " " + monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + " " + (dt.getDate());
            //console.log("i:"+i+"s:"+sateString);
            dateFlag = 0;
           var j = 0;
           for (j = 0; j < timesOffice.length; j++) {
                if (checkValidDateTime(sateString, timesOffice[j])) {
                    dateFlag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (firstdateString == "") firstdateString = sateString;
            dateOptions = dateOptions + '<option value="' + sateString + '">' + sateString + '</option>';

            i++;
        }
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $(".date").html(dateOptions);
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark thanks for that long reply but its not working only next 4 days are being shown :(

Answer (score 0):

As T.J Crowder said, you can use `Date.getDay()` to get the current weekday in the week. Giving some integer from `0` to `6` where `0` is *Sunday* and `6` is *Saturday*.

To show the next weekdays I supposed we don't want to print a bunch of numbers on the screen, so we can use a `weekdays` array to go from numbers to their corresponding text:

```
var weekdays = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
```

Now we can just use a `for` loop to scroll through these, starting from the todays day you get from using `.getDay()`. Note that if you go over we want to go back to `0`, so I'll use a separate variable `j` in the loop for that:

```
var weekdays = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();  // Current day
var numDays = 5;          // Number next days

for(var i = day; i <= day + numDays; i++ ) {
    var j = i;
    j = j % weekdays.length;
    console.log(weekdays[j]);
}
```

To show it can overflow and move back to Sunday, **[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qyv06m5/)** that prints the next 20 days.

To exclude Sunday, simply check that `if(j != 0)` , then print:

```
for(var i = day; i <= day + numDays; i++ ) {
    var j = i;
    j = j % weekdays.length;
    if( j != 0 ) 
        console.log(weekdays[j]); // Only prints non-Sundays
}
```

Although since today is Sunday, suppose you want to include Today's *Sunday*, but not the next *Sundays*. Simply change the if statement to `if( j != 0 || i == 0 )`, which will make an exception for the first element. **[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3qyv06m5/1/)** of that.